# Bootstrap grid with collapsed container in between

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, responsive, masonry

It's my very first question here and i hope you can help me. I'm trying to set up a product-overview page with the bootstrap grid. I have got 4 products in a row for large screen sizes. For smaller screen sizes i'd like to have 2 products per row.

The trick is, i want to have the product details in a collapsed container between the rows, that opens up, when i click on a product. It's working for the large screen sizes with 4 products. But how to achieve that the collapsed container is showing up right after the row, where i clicked my product, independent of how many products i have got per row. On smaller sizes the collapsed container opens after the second row, even if i click a product in the first row.

When i place every collapsed container right behind the product in the markup it pushes away the other products when i open it up.

Sorry, it's a bit complicated, i hope you know what i mean.

For better understanding have a look on my pen on codepen.

I want to keep it as simple as possible and I'm not sure which way to go?

http://codepen.io/auftakt/pen/PWxJVX

Tanks to all.

```js
$('.collapse-btn').on('click',function(){$('.collapse').collapse('hide');})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.img-responsive {
  width:100%;
}

.col-xs-6{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.product-detail {
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.no-padding-left {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.product-collapse-wrap > div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-1">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-collapse-wrap">
    <div id="Product-1" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 1</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Product-2" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 2</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Product-3" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 3</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Product-4" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 4</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-5">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-7" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-7">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <a class="collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product-8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product-8">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-collapse-wrap">
    <div id="Product-5" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 5</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Product-6" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 6</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Product-7" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 7</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Product-8" class="col-md-12 collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding-left">
          <div class="img-responsive product-detail" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Product 8</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Flachheizkörper</li>
            <li>Planheizkörper</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back, I answered a similar question here: [Bootstrap responsive grid layout (3 columns) with collapsed/hidden col-12 beneath each grid element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751609/bootstrap-responsive-grid-layout-3-columns-with-collapsed-hidden-col-12-beneat)

Basically you have to put the collapsed rows below the appropriate `col-*` to fit your smallest layout. So in your case:

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#one" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="//placehold.it/600"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#two" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="//placehold.it/600"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 overlay collapse" id="one">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 overlay collapse" id="two">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#three" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="//placehold.it/600"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#four" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="//placehold.it/600"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 overlay collapse" id="three">
               3
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 overlay collapse" id="four">
               4
            </div>
   </div>
```

And then you'd need some extra CSS to `overlay` the collapse column so that it's full width under the entire row on larger screens.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/0QGguzIYCx

For Bootstrap 4, this scenario is easier because of **flexbox ordering**..
http://codeply.com/go/qdUGPVL4HJ (alpha 6)

http://codeply.com/go/TLJi5MxQ1E (**Bootstrap 4.0.0**)
http://codeply.com/go/EsRR1nGa36  (**Bootstrap 4.3.0**)

---

It's also possible to use jQuery/JS to handle the ordering logic: 
https://codeply.com/p/Fs1zOQCk1q

Comment: Hey thanx a lot. Loks great. I will check it out and see if it's working. Looks much simpler in BS4. But it's still alpha. :-/

Comment: Once again. GREAT SOLUTION! Thanks a lot. I changed my project to BS4 and i works like a charm.