# Expand column inside Bootstrap css grid shifts other columns

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have a bootstrap grid that contain an expand component.

My actual problem is that when I expand one column, the other columns get shifted because they are in the same row.

I would like to know How can I make column independs each one to another

**expand component**

```
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Toggle
  </button>
</p>
<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div >
    <div class="">
      You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app component ( container )

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let card of cards; let index=index" class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-xl-4">
    <app-expend></app-expend>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what is happening

[image: What I get]

Here's what I expect

[image: What I expect]

Here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-independent-cards-wspez7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) to illustrate my actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Is accordion what you need? Check this example,
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: No it's not what I'm looking for, I have updated my question with illustration you can check it

Comment: Could you add number to each block?

Comment: I have should the solution on desktop but now i have another problem on mobile look here you have a link to actual solution on desktop
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025068/mobile-responsive-with-bootstrap-grid-and-expandable-columns