# mobile responsive with bootstrap grid and expandable columns

Tags: html, angular, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have created a bootstrap grid page and it's working as I want on desktop screen.

My actual problem is when I use mobile, I can't get how to reorder my cards in right way.

Here's my logic

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let col of [1,2]; let index=index" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-6">
    <div  *ngFor="let card of cards; let indexC=index" class='col-sm-12' >
      <app-expend  [card]="card" *ngIf="indexC%2===index"></app-expend> //card[1] = Hi1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason why I can't use a row with all colums inside is that When I expand other columns don't shift.

Here's a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-independent-cards-test-y9buuf?file=app/app.component.html)

What I expect is having column on mobile in this order

```
Hi1                Hi1
Hi2                Hi3
Hi3   Instead of   Hi5
Hi4                Hi2
Hi5                Hi4
Hi6                Hi6
```

And in desktop ( already done ) :

```
Hi1  Hi2  
Hi3  Hi4
Hi5  Hi6
```

the code should looks like something like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div  *ngFor="let card of cards; let indexC=index" class='col-sm-12' >
      <app-expend  [card]="card"></app-expend> //card[1] = Hi1
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

Comment: You cannot create that pattern with Bootstrap. You would need to change the order of the elements in your array on the component.

Comment: Refer [this](https://codepen.io/ondrejsvestka/pen/qmbeMe)

Comment: @TusharWalzade - Can you replicate the OP's use case in that example? Three rows placed beneath rather than a single row above?

Comment: I have two columns col1 contains Hi1,Hi3,Hi5 and col2 contains hi2,Hi4,hi6
given that my child cols are inside two parent cols, I don't see how to change order. Its possible to invert col1 and col2 but what I need is to mix child columns in order that Col1 contain Hi1,Hi2,Hi3 and Col2 contain Hi4,Hi5,Hi6

Comment: Alternatively, you could use CSS Grids - in which you can define the order in CSS.

Comment: Can you provide an example on stackblitz with css grid to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly when applied proper classes like - `col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12`. So your snipper would be -

```
<div class="row m-2">
    <div *ngFor="let card of cards; let indexC=index" class='col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12' >
      <app-expend  [card]="card"></app-expend>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check it live **[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-independent-cards-test-wai832?file=app/app.component.html)**, *try resizing the output window*.

- Snaps of output -

*1. On large screen*
[image: large screen]

*2. On small screen*

[image: small screen]*